# SQL Server with Oracle SQL Developer 4.1 - can't view tables

Tags: sql-server, oracle, azure, oracle-sqldeveloper

I cannot seem to browse the tables on my Azure SQL Server database from within Oracle SQL Developer (Version 4.1 - using jtds-1.3.1.jar plugin).

I can connect and perform all queries (inserts, selects, etc.), but when I try to expand it to view the tables, I see this error:

> An error was encountered performing the requested operation:
>
> Reference to database and/or server name in 'master..sysdatabases' is
>   not supported in this version of SQL Server.
>
> Vendor code 40515

Note: I tried rolling SQL Server back to version 3, and I'm getting the same error.

Please advise.  Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We're not certified for Azure..there's a similar problem in SQL 2014. The way we're asking for a list of tables isn't valid in that version. Would require an enhancement request to support Azure for Oracle Database Migrations.